# Google map info window not working

Tags: google-maps

Code @ http://pastebin.com/69XyvyWp

Paste code here to see 
http://www.w3schools.com/googleAPI/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_map_overlays_animate

Im new to coding, not sure what is wrong with it. Would really appreciate if anyone could educate me in this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do u mean the white speachbubble ? If yes take a look at the scriptcode. If there is a &iwloc=near
 than delete this , must be at the end of the code. Then the window should be showing

Comment: Yes! the bubble. I took a look at it and have not found any &iwloc=